# Вывод echo сообщений на экран

Tags: php, html

Подскажите, как вывести на экран результат кода? Где надо прописать echo или может что другое и как привязать кнопку `<p><input type="submit" value=Посчитать> </p>`, чтоб она работала?

```
<?
function square_roots($a, $b, $c)
{
    if ($a == 0)
        return false;

    if ($b == 0) {
        if ($c < 0) {
            $x1 = sqrt(abs($c / $a));            
            $x2 = sqrt(abs($c / $a));            
        } elseif ($c == 0) {
            $x1 = $x2 = 0;            
        } else {
            $x1 = sqrt($c / $a) . 'i';            
            $x2 = -sqrt($c / $a) . 'i';            
        }        
    } else {
        $d = $b * $b - 4 * $a * $c;        
        if ($d > 0) {
            $x1 = (-$b + sqrt($d)) / 2 * $a;            
            $x2 = (-$b - sqrt($d)) / 2 * $a;            
        } elseif ($d == 0) {
            $x1 = $x2 = (-$b) / 2 * $a;            
        } else {
            $x1 = -$b . '+' . sqrt(abs($d)) . 'i';            
            $x2 = -$b . '-' . sqrt(abs($d)) . 'i';            
        }        
    }

    return array(
        $x1,
        $x2
    );    
}
?>
```

-

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Решение квадратного уравнения </title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellspacing="0" style="width:100%">
<p>Введите a:
<input type="text" name="val1" size=10></p>

<p>Введите b:
<input type="text" name="val2" size=10></p>

<p>Введите c:
<input type="text" name="val3" size=10></p>

<p><input type="submit" value=Посчитать> </p>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @wolf123, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1):

По логике происходящего, вот так :

```
<?php
/*
здесь ваша функция
*/
$result = square_roots($a, $b, $c);
#
echo $result[0].' , '.$result[1];
?>
```

А что касаемо с кнопкой, то сейчас нет возможности вам объяснить.

Answer (score 0):

По поводу кнопки - есть масса вариантов

1) `<form action='index.php'></form>`

где index.php - файл в котором находится ваша функа и вызывается. Добивляем

`<input type='submit' value='Поехали!'>`,

при нажатии на нее будет происходить передача параметров на сткрипт. По умолчанию используется GET (когда даные видно в адресной строке). Но метод можно изменить на POST. Далее в скрипте принимаем данные и вуаля. Результат можно вывести как простыми есho, так и var_dump или print_r.

Лично я использую

`echo "<pre style='text-align:left'>"; print_r($array); echo "</pre>"; 
 получается симпатично`

2) Можно повесить на кнопку сабмита функу js.

`<input type='button' onclick='foo()'>`

3) ajax